# How can I replace characters in a dataframe using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where one of the columns have "MISSING" values along with numeric values, which I want to replace with NA. I know I could do it outside dplyr, but I want to keep it in `dplyr` toolchain.

```
read.csv('data.csv', header=F) %>% 
  select(V1,V4) %>% 
  mutate(V4=replace(V4, "MISSING", "NA"))
```

but this is throwing an error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `V4` must be length 30681 (the number of rows) or one, not 30682
```

Data

```
structure(list(V1 = c("01/01/1933", "01/02/1933", "01/03/1933", 
"01/04/1933", "01/05/1933"), V4 = c("MISSING", "MISSING", "MISSING", 
"MISSING", "MISSING")), .Names = c("V1", "V4"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x10280cf78>)
```

Comment: why not just `read.csv(..., na.strings = "MISSING")`?

Comment: You need `mutate(V4=replace(V4, V4=="MISSING", NA))` - check the documentation for `replace`. You also won't want quotes around `NA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dplyr::na_if` is designed for this purpose:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(V1 = c("01/01/1933", "01/02/1933", "01/03/1933", "01/04/1933", "01/05/1933"), 
                     V4 = c("MISSING", "MISSING", "MISSING", "MISSING", "MISSING")), 
                .Names = c("V1", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df %>% mutate(V4 = na_if(V4, 'MISSING'))
#>           V1   V4
#> 1 01/01/1933 <NA>
#> 2 01/02/1933 <NA>
#> 3 01/03/1933 <NA>
#> 4 01/04/1933 <NA>
#> 5 01/05/1933 <NA>
```

Really, it's better to take care of this task on import, though, e.g. with the `na.strings` parameter of `read.csv` or `data.table::fread` or the `na` parameter of `readr::read_csv`.

Also, your data is currently a data.table (likely because you used `fread`), which has its own grammar for `[`. If you want to use `fread` but keep the result a standard data.frame, set `data.table = FALSE` in `fread`.

Comment: `na.strings = "MISSING"`

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without specifying the column

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% replace(.=="MISSING", NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that the word "MISSING" appears in some fields in the CSV file, and you'd like those to be replaced with the `NA` value (not, and this is important, the string "NA").

For this, I would recommend the `read_csv` function from the `readr` package. It's faster and has an `na` argument that sets what strings in your file mean `NA`.

```r
readr::read_csv(
"one,two,three
1,MISSING,5
2,,3
text,NA,MISSING", na = c("NA", "MISSING", ""))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>     one   two three
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1     1  <NA>     5
#> 2     2  <NA>     3
#> 3  text  <NA>    NA
```